# AWS Lambda Connection To MySQL DB on RDS Times Out Intermittently

Tags: python, mysql, aws-lambda, sqlalchemy, amazon-rds

To get my feet wet with deploying Lambda functions on AWS, I wrote what I thought was a simple one: calculate the current time and write it to a table in RDS. A separate process triggers the lambda every 5 minutes. For a few hours it will work as expected, but after some time the connection starts to hang. Then, after a few hours, it will magically work again. Error message is

```
(pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, \"Can't connect to MySQL server on '<server info redacted>' (timed out)\")
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

The issue is not with the VPC, or else the lambda wouldn't run at all I don't think. I have tried defining the connection outside the lambda handler (as many suggest), inside the handler, closing the connection after every run; now, I have the main code running in a separate helper function the lambda handler calls. The connection is created, used, closed, and even explicitly deleted within a try/except block. Still, the intermittent connection issue persists. At this point, I am not sure what else to try. Any help would be appreciated; thank you! Code is below:

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import event as eventSA

# This function is something I added to fix an issue with writing floats
def add_own_encoders(conn, cursor, query, *args):
    cursor.connection.encoders[np.float64] = lambda value, encoders: float(value)
def writeTestRecord(event):
    try:
        connStr = "mysql+pymysql://user:pwd@server.host:3306/db"
        engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(connStr)
        eventSA.listen(engine, "before_cursor_execute", add_own_encoders)
        conn = engine.connect()
        
        timeRecorded = pd.Timestamp.now().tz_localize("GMT").tz_convert("US/Eastern").tz_localize(None)
        s = pd.Series([timeRecorded,])
        s=s.rename("timeRecorded")
        s.to_sql('lambdastest',conn,if_exists='append',index=False,dtype={'timeRecorded':sqlalchemy.types.DateTime()})
        
        conn.close()
        del conn
        del engine
        
        return {
            'success' : 'true',
            'dateTimeRecorded' : timeRecorded.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        }
    except:
        conn.close()
        del conn
        del engine
        return {
            'success' : 'false'
        }

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    toReturn = writeTestRecord(event)
    return toReturn
```

Comment: Please try adding finally block after try & catch block. Add the close statement inside Finally block.                                                                                                                   
       finally {
  finallyCode - Block of code to be executed regardless of the try / catch result
}

Comment: Try using this https://github.com/jeremydaly/serverless-mysql. Serverless MySQL adds a connection management component to the mysql module that is designed specifically for use with serverless applications. This module constantly monitors the number of connections being utilized, and then based on your settings, manages those connections to allow thousands of concurrent executions to share them. It will clean up zombies, enforce connection limits per user, and retry connections using trusted backoff algorithms.It has been tested with AWS's RDS MySQL, Aurora MySQL, and Aurora Serverless.